# No paged query var being set in WordPress custom pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have everything set up fine I just need to finish the pagination. This method is the same as I have done before but for some reason it is now having issues.

I am using the standard 'posts' post type and getting all posts (1 per page like this)

```
$pageNumber = ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 );

$posts = new WP_Query([
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => 1,
   'paged' => $pageNumber
]);
```

This does what I need but $pageNumber is always 1.

When doing a check on the query var for paged:

```
if (get_query_var('paged')) {
    echo "paged:" . get_query_var('paged');
} else {
    echo "no paged set";
}
```

It will always say no paged set.

In my pagination the link I am using for paged links is:

```
domain.com/blog/page/2
```

This returns the correct page and doesn't 404, but the page is not being picked up.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the issue here was that my query var for page was actually 'page' not paged.

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

I was able to see all the query vars with the above code.

Comment: I was facing a similar problem.

On a public page the pagination works as expected.
But on a private page the pagination didn't work due to the query var wasn't page as expected. It was paged. Therefore I altered the code and now it is working as it should. But I was searching why the query vars differs based on the status of the page and haven't find anything yet. If anyone know why this happens please let me know.

Comment: Update: I've found a really good explanation on another post. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180784/what-is-the-difference-between-paged-and-page#